# when i run this code gives Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php

```
<?php
    require('config.php');
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    }else{
    $form =<<<EOT
    <form action="reg.php" method="POST">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="name"/><br />
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"/><br />
        Username: <input type="text" name="uname"/><br />
        Email: <input type="text" name="email1"/><br />
        Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email2"/><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="pass1"/><br />
        Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2"/><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit"/>
    </form>
    EOT;
    echo $form;
    }
?>
```

Comment: can you share your whole code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have intendation when beginning and ending the definition of EOT ... ...look at code below. It's not nice (it screws up the intendation for the rest of the code), but this is the only way.

```
<?php
    require('config.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    }else{
$form =<<<EOT
    <form action="reg.php" method="POST">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="name"/><br />
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"/><br />
    Username: <input type="text" name="uname"/><br />
    Email: <input type="text" name="email1"/><br />
    Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email2"/><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass1"/><br />
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit"/>
    </form>
EOT;
    }

    echo $form;

?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Your "EOT" can't be indented, it has to be in the beginning of the line (sadly).

Comment: Why "sadly"? I can easily understand this behavior. If it has *anything* behind it, how can you be sure the author intended to end the string, and not just include it there?

Comment: @Madara well, as you can see it breaks indentation, effectively taking away the syntax's usefulness in properly structured code (at least for me personally). I'd much favour a behaviour that allows the end string to appear anywhere in the string.